# are there singularity points in a hyperbola?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

We can define the points of the hyperbola on the left side of the directrix with the following polar coordinates $r = \frac{ed}{1+e \cos \theta}$, where $e > 1$ is the eccentricity and $d$ is the positive distance from focus point to the directrix. The points on the right side of the directrix are $r = \frac{ed}{e \cos \theta - 1}$.

What happens on the left side when the $\cos \theta = -\frac{1}{e}$? Similarly what happens on the right side when $\cos \theta = \frac{1}{e}$? If those thetas are not on hyperbola, is it because past that point the $r$ would be negative, so it is impossible?

Thanks!

Comment: That "singularity" corresponds to the point at infinity.

Comment: Your theta corresponds to the asymptotes

Comment: Thanks! To close the question, can you just copy this to the answer?

Comment: Is an answer to your problem useful to you?

Comment: Now that I know it, I don't need it anymore, but then I should delete the question as well I guess? :)

Comment: Not necessarily dear friend, questioning yourself about some kind of problems is a good sign and your question,  being unimportant was not banal though.